# What is the proper way import python modules for dev_appserver?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, import

## Intent

I am creating a CRUD app for App Engine where the user authenticates via OAuth and the server stores their access and refresh tokens in Datastore. I am doing local testing with `dev_appserver` and getting stuck between a rock and hard place:

- <s>The python37 runtime cannot import the `ndb` module for Datastore and</s> the python27 runtime cannot import the `google.auth` module.

## Problem Statement

### <s>Python37</s>

<s>In the python37 runtime, my requirements.txt file is detected and all dependencies are installed properly. However, it appears that this runtime does not currently have native support for the `ndb` module in order to make calls the Datastore API.</s>

```
    from google.appengine.ext import ndb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine'
```

<s>One way to solve my problem would be to manually install the ndb package, however I don't believe that it open-source at this point in time.</s>

I will most likely move forward by using `google-api-python-client` to interact with Datastore. However, I am still interested in solving the problem outlined below in order to better my understanding of the way python modules work in App Engine.

### Python27

In the python27 runtime, requirements.txt is ignored. My workaround has been to include the latest releases of all of the dependencies' source code. I do this by populating a directory called `dependencies` with the source and then add symbolic links to root modules. (This has also been a nice exercise in learning how importing python modules works)

## Project Structure

### Directory

```
.
├── api.py
├── app
│   ├── build
│   ├── config
│   ├── dist
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── src
│   └── static
├── app.yaml
├── dependencies
│   ├── click-7.0
│   ├── flask-1.0.2
│   ├── google-auth-library-python-1.6.3
│   ├── google-auth-library-python-oauthlib-0.3.0
│   ├── itsdangerous-1.1.0
│   ├── jinja-2.10.1
│   └── markupsafe-1.1.1
├── libs
│   ├── click -> ../dependencies/click-7.0/click/
│   ├── flask -> ../dependencies/flask-1.0.2/flask/
│   ├── google -> ../dependencies/google-auth-library-python-1.6.3/google/
│   ├── google_auth_oauthlib -> ../dependencies/google-auth-library-python-oauthlib-0.3.0/google_auth_oauthlib/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── itsdangerous -> ../dependencies/itsdangerous-1.1.0/src/itsdangerous/
│   ├── jinja2 -> ../dependencies/jinja-2.10.1/jinja2/
│   └── markupsafe -> ../dependencies/markupsafe-1.1.1/src/markupsafe/
├── requirements.txt
└── spa.py
```

### Python Code

In my server files, `spa.py` and `api.py`, I include `libs` in the python path as follows:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'libs'))
```

This works for import statements such as

```
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow  # works
```

and

```
from flask import Flask, request, session, redirect  # works
```

but it fails for

```
import google.auth  # does not work
```

with the exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<HOME>/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "<HOME>/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "<HOME>/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "<HOME>/vue-scheduler/api.py", line 6, in <module>
    import google.auth
  File "<HOME>/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/sandbox.py", line 1149, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named google.auth
```

I believe I've set everything up correctly for python to import the `auth` submodule. The `__init__.py` files are present and that *should* let python recurse through the nested module directories. However it isn't able to find `auth`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 1st generation GAE standard environment (Python 2.7) application handling dependencies is a bit different than for a regular Python application. Try not to get creative as it'll be more difficult to get help if you get in trouble.

For the libraries included in the GAE-provided 3rd party built-in libraries you can [just request them](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#using_a_built-in_third-party_library_bundled_with_the_runtime) in your `app.yaml` file.

The 3rd party libraries not provided by GAE (or those for which you intentionally want to use your own versions/copies) must be [copied/vendored-in](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library) into your application.

Choose one method only, attempting to do both for the same library may cause trouble as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `ndb` ORM library is not available for Python 3. You can either:

1. Access [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/) through the Cloud Datastore API. You can use the [Google Cloud client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries) to store and retrieve data from Cloud Datastore.
2. Wait for `ndb` to be ported to Python 3. This is currently in progress, you can follow along here: https://github.com/Googleapis/python-ndb

Continuing to use the Python 2.7 runtime is not recommended, as Python 2.7 will reach end-of-life on January 1st, 2020.

Comment: This was my major concern. Developing for a runtime that will deprecated in less than a year seemed silly to begin with. I guess I'm surprised the ndb library for python3 isn't out yet, even with that encroaching deadline. I will probably move forward by using `googleapis`. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: To be clear: the runtime will not be deprecated on that date. That version of the language will no longer be supported by the Python Software Foundation on that date, which means no new releases or versions.

Comment: Excited to hear the ndb will be support for Python 3.  I hope it provides the same caching features as for Python 2.